# iOS 8.2 UIRequiresPersistentWiFi not working

Tags: ios, wifi

I am making an app that requires consistent wifi connection. The problem is that when the wifi is off and I turn on the app nothing happens, even though I have activated the UIRequiresPersistentWiFi flag. Also when the screen locks, and I go to the app after unlocking, it also can't use the wifi. The only solution that I have found for this problem is the activation of UIRequiresPersistentWiFi, which clearly doesn't work in my app, or I am not doing it right. So does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` doesn't force the device to connect to WiFi when the app is launched, it only specifies that an existing WiFi connection should be kept open for the duration your app is running. The default behaviour is for iOS to drop its WiFi connection after 30 minutes to conserve battery life.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) for more detail.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but I have also encountered many statements (not official) saying that if an app requires wifi, and the wifi is not enabled, then i can present the user with a system dialog that would send him to the wifi options screen. Is that possible?

Comment: This only happens when no known WiFi networks are in range and user hasn't disabled this option in Settings: `Settings->WiFi->Ask to Join Networks`. I don't think that `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` has any affect on this alert.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into this matter from another angle. I will accept Your answer as it has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: The Apple documentation does say that a network selection dialog should be displayed. `The inclusion of this key lets the system know that it should display the network selection dialog if it detects any active Wi-Fi hot spots` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html section "Using Wi-Fi"). But the actual behavior (tested on iOS 9.2) does not display anything.